# How can I empty the trash using terminal?

Tags: command-line, trash

I am not able to find **trash** anywhere. Can you please tell me a command or anything like that to empty the trash using terminal ?

Comment: This was posted 3 years ago.  We need something that spells this out including what version it works for here in 2017

Answer (score 467, accepted):

You can use the `rm` command:

```
rm -rf ~/.local/share/Trash/*
```

The `rm` command removes (deletes) files or directories.

```
-f, --force     Ignore nonexistant files, and never prompt before removing.
-r, -R, --recursive     Remove directories and their contents recursively.
```

The trash folder is found at: `$HOME/.local/share/Trash`

Be careful how you use the `rm` command - the files aren't sent to a trash can where you can undelete them, so it's not easy to undo.

Comment: ~ always means /home/currentuser? I mean it is fixed?

Comment: This wont work if the trash is somewhere else.

Comment: @hellodear2 Notice that `~` is only a shell-specific thing, which expands to your home directory path. Using, e.g. `"~/some/path"` won't expand because of quoting. Likewise, not all file managers will understand `~` if you enter it in address bar.

Comment: Sensitive system folders and files cannot be removed without privileges, and `rm` cannot remove folders at all, unless you give it the `-r` (or equivalent) option. However using `rm` without proper care may case loss of lost of important _personal_ files, especially if used with wildcard arguments.

Comment: @Ruslan so ~ won't work on each and every system? How much specific is it? Can you please clarify? When can I say ~ is equivalent to /home/user ? Thanks.

Comment: @hellodear2 see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16862718/no-such-file-or-directory-ls-in-conjunction-with-tilde-expansion) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15493928/shell-tilde-expansion-does-not-work-when-passed-as-an-option) questions for examples when tilde doesn't appear to work (these are about bash though). I don't really know what specific shells don't support it, but you should understand that tilde is implemented not on file system level, but on the level of application. XFE is an example of file manager which doesn't understand `~` in address bar.

Comment: why is this seemingly approx. 100 times faster than clicking trash "empty" in any file browser?

Comment: @Blauhirn: I don't know for sure, but with `rm` I'd *guess* a single file (the trash can) gets unlinked while with the GUI maybe this is done for each file (and we can see the `Trash` directory is still present at home dir). If there is a lot of stuff in the trash can, it might take some time to sever all links when done one at a time. [related post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/10883/86552)

Comment: Trash directory has three directories in it. 
1) expunged
2) files
3) info
Expunged is empty, files have files as shown in trash bin while info has all file names with extension .info
Should I follow the above method which will remove these three directories or should I just remove from files and info directories.

Comment: Deleting this broke my trash bin: after doing it, I couldn't send files to trash anymore (couldn't write to ~/.local/share/Trash/info/*.trashinfo)

Comment: One reason for `rm` to be faster is that real trash methods delete *your* trashes in all places (as above, on memory stick, another disk, ...).

Comment: that folder does not exist

Comment: This asks `sure you want to delete the only file` question would it be possible to prevent it?

Answer (score 222):

After you `sudo apt install trash-cli`, you can do

```
trash-empty
```

More interesting details about trash handling below and in [the man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man1/trash-empty.1.html).

```sh
restore-trash (1)    - Restore for Command line trash utility.
trash (1)            - Command line trash utility.
trash-empty (1)      - Empty for Command line trash utility.
trash-list (1)       - List trashed files.
trash-put (1)        - Command line trash utility.
trash-rm (1)         - Removes files matching a pattern from the trash can
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. If you have an USB stick in, for example, the files you trash in it will be put in an hidden directory in the root of the device (at least it happened last time I checked) `.Trash-$UID` - so in this case the trash is physically in two different places...

Comment: So sad that you have to install a package just to empty the trash. Counting the trash against the disk space is one of the most annoying features of Ubuntu.

Comment: @Michael "Trash" is a feature provided by the desktop manager, which is a layer above the stuff that you would usually use in the command line.    Really all it does is move files into a hidden folder on the same device, and store some metadata so they can be put back into place if the user would like.  You don't actually reclaim any space until you "empty" the trash, which is when the file is actually deleted.

Comment: It should be noted that this command is user specific.  I installed it and was scratching my head about why it wasn't working til I realized the files were in the trash of another user.

Comment: I find it helpful to run `baobab` as `sudo` so one can inspect all the trash bins across users and devices. I've had it happen a few times that files were in `root`'s trash, which would not get deleted when the user emptied the trash...

Comment: The only solution that works for me! Thanks!

Comment: I like, elegant

Comment: `trash-list` returns empty even `~/.local/share/Trash/files` contains files

Answer (score 58):

You are looking for the `$XDG_DATA_HOME/Trash` directory. The trash directory is defined in the "Desktop Trash Can Specification" of the [freedesktop site](http://freedesktop.org/wiki/Specifications/trash-spec/). This variable is normally not available in the terminal windows, hence you will need for `trash-empty`. This command follows all the specification of the Freedesktop.org and it's intelligent enough to find out where the Trash is. You will need to install it first.

There are other tools for this, like `gvfs-trash --empty` which can also send items to the Trash can.

Comment: +1 for `$XDG_DATA_HOME`. How did you get that?

Comment: @Jobin is all in the specification. http://www.ramendik.ru/docs/trashspec.html

Comment: @Braiam Can you please elaborate more? How can I use it? I am not getting how it is solving my purpose. Please explain a little bit. And I don't want to trash the items, I want to empty the trash.

Comment: @hellodear2 `trash-empty` [empties the trash](https://github.com/andreafrancia/trash-cli#usage). You only need to run it. The binary is in the `trash-cli` package. Is the same as jhort solution just that I explain where it comes from and offer another tool.

Comment: Now `gio trash --empty`, at least on Ubuntu 18.10/Gnome 3.

Comment: Oneliner with fallback if the variable is unset: `rm -rf ${XDG_DATA_HOME:-$HOME/.local/share}/Trash/*`

Answer (score 17):

With trash-cli installed type `trash-empty` I've used this successfully to empty the trash across different drives and numerous locations.

to install trash-cli type
 `sudo apt-get install trash-cli`

Or you could [use this script](https://askubuntu.com/a/727758/225694) to do it for you.

Comment: This looks safer

Answer (score 1):

Please note, `~/.local/share/Trash/*` might not be the only location that stores the trashed files, so removing that path is not enough if you have other partitions that also have a trash folder.

If you want to empty the trash in all available partitions, you can use the following command to empty the trash:

```
gio trash --empty
```

`gio` is provided by glib2, which is used by most GTK-based applications, and the `gio` binary should be available out-of-the-box in most of the cases if you are using a desktop environment. If not, you can install it via:

```
apt-get install libglib2.0-bin
```