# I need help with BleachBit

Tags: root, ubuntu-mate, bleachbit

I am using Ubuntu MATE 16.04.1. I wanted to use BleachBit.
First, I ran BleachBit and clicked on "Preview".
It showed 556 MB cache, and I wanted to delete it, but when I tried it, the program said, that I need root permissions.
When I start BleachBit with root Permissions and click on "Preview", it says the Cache is 0 Byte.
My Hard Disk isn't that big, so 556 MB are very much for my Hard Disk.

Could Somebody help me?
--nonick

Comment: It would help to know the path of the file that was permission denied. I am guessing it is owned by root by located in the user path (`/home/(username)/`). When you run BleachBit as root, it does not clean the non-root user's account.

Comment: @Andrew Yes, it is in the user Folder

Answer (score 1):

Try [this link](https://askubuntu.com/a/507174/110324) to launch Nautilus as root

Or you can run BleachBit as root, but instead of the standard mode with the check boxes and big delete button, click **File - Shred** from the menu. Then navigate to the folder `/home/your_username/.local/share/Trash`. You may want to delete the whole folder

Or from the command line try this to delete the whole trash folder

```
rm -rf ~/.local/share/Trash
```