# Ubuntu's terrible trash

Tags: nautilus, sudo, trash

I've got 18.5 GB of trash in my trash, I've tried emptying it, but it won't work, even when I navigate to trash folder as root within nautilus.

Comment: Take a look at this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/468721/how-can-i-empty-the-trash-using-terminal

Comment: @EduardoLópez Instead of posting a comment, in the future leave it as an answer with clear indication of where you got the information. For example if that page ever got deleted, that comment would be useless

Comment: @DavidCole thanks for the hint. I wrongly assumed it was better not to repeat the information again :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As taken from [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/468721/how-can-i-empty-the-trash-using-terminal),

You can use this command :

```
sudo rm -rf ~/.local/share/Trash/*
```

The rm command removes (delete) files or directories.

```
-f, --force     Ignore nonexistant files, and never prompt before removing.
-r, -R, --recursive     Remove directories and their contents recursively.
```

The trash folder is found at: `$HOME/.local/share/Trash`

Be careful how to use rm command because any misuse may cause deleting sensitive system folders and files .

Comment: Oops, I'll make sure to add that sudo! I forget :) @draoi