# Empty trash hangs

Tags: trash

I deleted several thousands of large files at once with total volume of 500Gb.
They ended up in a trash bin (I thought I was using shift-delete, but apparently it was just moved to recycling bin.
When I choose "empty recycling bin" it freezes.

```
i@my_comp:~/.local/share/Trash/files$ ls
i@my_comp:~/.local/share/Trash/files$
```

Hence, suggested `rm -rf *` from inside `~/.local/share/Trash/files` 
Deleted files still appear in recycling bin.

---

This question IS NOT a duplicate because FILES REMAIN in trash AFTER
`rm -rf ~/.local/share/Trash/*`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I empty the trash using terminal?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/468721/how-can-i-empty-the-trash-using-terminal)

Comment: NOT DUPLICATE. See edited question.

Comment: What output do you get for `rm -rf ~/.local/share/Trash/*` and what output for `ls -l ~/.local/share/Trash/`. Please edit your question and update with the output.

Comment: Are any of the files owned by other than you? Please try: `sudo rm -rf ~/.local/share/Trash/files/*`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was caused by 10000 of small (4Kb) files. Empty trash was working, but slowly. I thought process hung and started it over again. I left it overnight and the bin was clean.

Comment: This is not normal, deleting 10 000 small files should only take a few seconds.

Comment: I my case these files also were originated from a different mounted device, so maybe this was one of the factors of slowness. trash-empty command helped

Answer (score 3):

**Option #1:**

You can try the command-line utility `trash-cli`, to use it to empty the trash from the command-line:

1. Install the package, run the following in the terminal:

   `sudo apt install trash-cli`
2. Empty trash, run the following in the terminal:

   `trash-empty`

This is the equivalent to **empty trash** in the GUI but it works by itself and does not rely on the GUI.

**Option #2:**

Please check if there are hidden files in the `Trash` directory, to do so run the following command in the terminal:

```
ls -la ~/.local/share/Trash/
```

Hidden files start with `.` like `.filename`. If there are hidden files, you can run the following command in the terminal to delete them:

```
rm -rfv ~/.local/share/Trash/.??*
```