# Unable to delete folder located in "Trash" in Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS

Tags: permissions, nautilus, samba, trash

I am trying to delete a folder that I imported from a MacOS device using SMB, but I have not yet found a way to delete it. I tried using the Nautilus utility to gain permissions to delete the folder, but it did not work. I also obtain the same results when trying to restore the folder. The error occurs even when elevating the account, The folder is quite small in size, 1 GB approximately.

Any ideas?

Error message:

[image: You do not have sufficient permissions to delete]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Empty trash hangs](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1163428/empty-trash-hangs)

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu, `trash-empty` command is safer. `sudo apt install trash-cli` https://askubuntu.com/questions/468721/how-can-i-empty-the-trash-using-terminal?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 1):

You always have the permission to do anything on Linux (Ubuntu in this case). Whenever you are prompted with

> You don't have sufficient permission

always use sudo. Except when you are not a sudo user, in which case you can't do anything.

Use the terminal to gain sudo access.

1. Open trash by typing `cd .local/share/Trash` in terminal.
2. Type `sudo rm -rf *` sudo gives you the permission, rm is the command to remove and -rf is the force remove flag, and * means everything. i.e., it will empty you trash.
3. If you want to delete a particular file then instead of step 2 type `sudo rm -rf FileName` which in your case FileName is 'Videos Edit'.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I managed to follow your steps within the terminal but without success. The folder still remains in the Trash folder. Kind Regards!

Comment: @peter Type "sudo su" and then the password. And then again try "rm -rf Videos Edit" command in the trash directory. It should not make any difference but try once.

Comment: be carefull to rmeove only the files/ directory to actually need to be removed

Answer (score 0):

Try to do it with root permissions:

1. Open terminal window (ctrl + alt + t)
2. Type `sudo rm -rf /.local/share/Trash/*` fro remove all Trash content with root permissions

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. I attempted this step without success. The folder is still there for some reason, no matter if I attempt from the terminal or Files.