# Empty trash every 30 minutes

Tags: ubuntu-mate, trash

I would like my trash emptied every 30 minutes.

I installed Autotrash, but it specified days of age.

Is there an alternative?

Comment: this sounds like a good candidate for a cronjob. Have you looked into that route?

Comment: I second the `cron` nomination and this can help doing it from command line: https://askubuntu.com/questions/468721/how-can-i-empty-the-trash-using-terminal

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix I saw how to empty from the command line, but not in a specified time interval.

Comment: @Nmath Could you give me some more details on how to do that?

Comment: [how to run cron job every 30 minutes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/584770/how-would-i-get-a-cron-job-to-run-every-30-minutes)

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix The cronjob is running now. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a simple script file and set it up in `cron` to run every 30 minutes.

Create a new file with your script.  You can put it anyplace.  In this example, we will put the script in your home directory's `~/.config`

```
sudo nano ~/.config/emptytrash30.sh
```

Add the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
find /home/yourname/.local/share/Trash/expunged/ -type f -exec rm {} \;
find /home/yourname/.local/share/Trash/files/ -type f -exec rm {} \;
find /home/yourname/.local/share/Trash/info/ -type f -exec rm {} \;
```

Save <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd>, and exit <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>.

Make the script executable:

```
chmod +x ~/.config/emptytrash30.sh
```

Now set up `cron` to run the script every 30 minutes:

```
crontab -e
```

*Choose an editor if you've never used cron before.*

Add the following at the end:

```
*/30 * * * * /home/yourname/.config/emptytrash30.sh
```

This tells `cron` to execute your script every 30 minutes of every hour on every day, on every day of the week, on every day of the month.

Save <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd>, and exit <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>.

Comment: I had to add this to the script. find /media/andy/MAXTOR_SDB2/.Trash-1000/files/ -type f -exec rm {} \;
@Mirabeau

Comment: Yes you can of course add the "trash" of other HDs, as long as you understand the trick, no problem.
Be careful, however, not to take the wrong path or make a typing error;)
Remember to validate the answer if it meets your expectations: D